# Android 2 table : error code=1,msg= no such table: valuetable

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Hello I need some help with my android database, becouse i search a lot what should be the problem, but nothing help in this, and i hope someone can help me in this case (I am a beginer android developer.) The first table working just the valuetable don't.
Here is my code:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
public class DbConstans
{   
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="mydatabase";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=2;

SQLiteDatabase db;
Context ctx;
DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
MyValues mvhelper;

public DbConstans(Context context)
{
    this.ctx=context;
    dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    mvhelper=new MyValues(ctx);

}

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE="logintable";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME="username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="password";
    public static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table "+ DATABASE_TABLE +" ( "+ KEY_ID +
             " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_USERNAME + " text not null, " + KEY_PASSWORD
              + " text not null);";
public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLException {

        try{
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST logintable");
        onCreate(db);

    }
    }

    public class MyValues extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME2="valuetable";
        public static final String KEY_ID1="id";
        public static final String KEY_FMON="money";

        public static final String TABLE_CREATE2="create table " + DATABASE_NAME2 + 
                " ( " + KEY_ID1 + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_FMON +
                 " text not null);";

        public MyValues(Context context)
        {super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) throws SQLException{

            try{
                db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE2);
            }catch(SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST"+TABLE_CREATE2);
            onCreate(db);
        }
        }

    public DbConstans open()
    {
        dbhelper=new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
        db=dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    mvhelper=new MyValues(ctx);
        db=mvhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        dbhelper.close();
        mvhelper.close();
    }

    public long register(String user, String pasw)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues=new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_USERNAME, user);
        initialValues.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_PASSWORD, pasw);

        return db.insertOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

    }

    public boolean login(String username,String passw)
    {
        Cursor mcursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE username=? AND password=?", new String[]{username,passw});
        if (mcursor!=null)
        {
            if (mcursor.getCount() > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    return false;
    }

    public long mon(String fmon)
    {
        ContentValues initVal=new ContentValues();
        initVal.put(MyValues.KEY_FMON, fmon);
        return db.insertOrThrow(MyValues.DATABASE_NAME2, null, initVal);
    }

    public Cursor returnMon()
    {
        return db.query(MyValues.DATABASE_NAME2,new String[]{MyValues.KEY_FMON},null,null,null,null,null);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same database name for both helpers:

```
public MyValues(Context context)
    {super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
```

should be `DATABASE_NAME2` according to your code.

What happens that the database `DATABASE_NAME` already exists and is of correct version so `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()` do not get run.

However, consider combining the helpers into one unless you really want to have two separate databases.

Comment: I thought  that I can create 2 table and link them in one database,but then should I create 2 database and work with them? Maybe this is an idiot question, but Isn't it demand more memory?